# Is a vented gas fire pit in a covered deck a bad idea?

Tags: venting, fire-pit

We are building a home and desire to have a covered deck with a gas fire pit. Some websites say no problem, but when speaking with a dealer of gas fire pits, they were opposed to the idea because the heat would be dangerous, even with a 9 foot ceiling. The following link shows a covered porch with a vent in the ceiling. Would this actually work or is it still a bad idea?

[Example image of a gas fire pit under a vent of a covered porch](https://www.houzz.com/photos/covered-patio-and-firepit-craftsman-patio-seattle-phvw-vp%7E11042212)

Comment: All heating devices have minimum distances from flammable surfaces in all directions.  If the distances for that device are less, then for heat you should be okay, if the local fire and building departments allow it.   CO detectors are recommended also, inside the house and on the deck.

Comment: As long as you have a place for the heat to go as that one has there is no problem, they even have them inside homes, if the space is not enclosed there is no need for a CO detector but inside an open flue like this requires a CO interlock to the gas valve in some jurisdictions.

Comment: I don't think you'll have a fire risk unless you have some roaring monster of a gas fire pit.  I have one under a wooden ceiling and the problem I have is condensation. Remember that water vapor (esp. nat gas or propane) is a byproduct of combustion.   I have to clean off mildew a couple of times a year, so I think it would a  good idea to vent it. You may not need to use a powered fan, convection might be enough, but I'm not sure, so you'll need to do some more research. Hmmm...I learned from your question....maybe I'll install a vent!  Thanks!